# Database tasks inside asynctask or no

Tags: android, database, sqlite

Should I perform every single DB related operation inside an asynctask ? (or similar background processing thread).. even for example small operations like updating a single column value ? or adding a 3 columned row into the db ?

Comment: I think, you do not need to put in Asynctask because this operation fast and it do not block UI thread.

Comment: For "small operations" you don't need to. Other is when your queries involve 5 joined tables and you return several fields OR when you import/export a table on a csv file.

Answer (score 1):

That really depends on how much time that operation takes. Long running operations will make UI thread wait, and app will appear to be frozen.

The code you now have may appear to be very quick but regard future circumstances carefully. Database may grow too large or there may be an IO lag etc.

Also consider frequency of such operation, a separate database query when each item of a `ListView` is being scrolled into view is not really efficient.

But if its an un-frequent work and its clear that it would *always* take a very very small time to run, there is nothing wrong with doing it on UI thread.

Comment: S.D you are a genius.